# I know Wi-Fi, but what on earth is Wi-Fi__33?

Tags: ieee-802.11

Thank you for reviewing my question. I am researching "Wi-Fi__33". It's a real thing. I see it mentioned in places such as http://www.logisticsit.com/blog/2017/02/07/three-retail-tech-trends-to-watch-in/, and http://www.omega.com/technical-learning/next-industrial-revolution.html, but I find no definition of it anywhere. I think it may be used in payments, retail, and/or Industry 4.0. It could be quite new. I could really use a definition.

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources.

Comment: Possibly the 3 ghz band stuff? Mostly inapplicable in the US at this time, (AFAIK, or requires a license that makes it prohibitive for most) but seen elsewhere in the world.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I really think this is a copy paste error (trademark symbol unicode error?).

Look at this http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/panasonic_PAN9310_9320%20Series.pdf
One component is clearly indicated as a Wifi__33 whereas another reference of the same product is normal "Wifi"

but the [Official datasheet](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/downloads/files/panasonic-pan9310-9320-datasheet.pdf) indicate that only the antenna differ.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi___33 is an auto correct option in Office 365 products, why that is who knows. It often overrides Wi-Fi as an auto correct option. A copy writer could make a fast auto correct change and not notice it, hence this is popping up, despite it not being a reference to a standard or protocol.

Comment: Do you have any support for this? If so, you should include the relevant text and a link for attribution.

Comment: @Ron Maupin not sure what 'relevant text and link' refer to but here's support for phantomfive's assertion. [![word 2016 spellcheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEDE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEDE.png)